# __autoload does not run?

Tags: php, oop, autoload

I have a file structure that looks like this;

```
/
/public
  -index.php
  -login.php
/config.php
/init.php
/classes/ClassGroup/ClassName.class.php
```

__autoload is defined in config.php, with absolute path to classes.
config.php is required in index.php, but when I try to initiate a new class;

```
$user = new User_User;
```

Results in;

```
Fatal error: Class 'User_User' not found in /......./public/index.php on line 27
```

It does not find it, and when trying to echo out something at the very start of __autoload(), it doesnt do that either, so it seems to me that it does not run the function when not finding a class.
Anyone have a clue what the problem might be?

```
function __autoload($class){
    //echo "autoloader started";
    $pieces = explode('_', $class);
    $path = __SITE_PATH.'/classes';
    foreach( $pieces as $i ){
        $path .=  '/'.$i;
    }
    //echo "trying to include " .$path.".class.php";
    require_once( $path . '.class.php' );
}
```

Comment: Lets see the autoloading function...

Comment: you can use array get_included_files() to check wich files are included.

Comment: I not understood your file structure. Can you organize it better?

Comment: @MarcelColomb What does that have to do with auto loading? "*My house has no electricity*" "*Don't worry - you can use some water by a petrol station to clean your car*".

Comment: If you echo something in the config.php, it echoes it?

Comment: Please, use `spl_autoload_register` instead of `__autoload`. Add some output right before defining `__autoload` and after as well, to see that you're actually defining it as you assume. `get_included_files` are useful to see if `__autoload` actually tried to load a file, but if you don't see any output from the `__autoload` function at all, that probably won't work. It'll tell you if the config is loaded, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, apparently this function is not being called automatically.
Here is the fix;

```
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

This worked.

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a workaround. The function __autoload is a magic function. It redefines the autoload. If it is not being called then another problem is going on.

Comment: From php.net:Tip
spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Comment: You ask why __autoload does not work. You answer to that problem with "Do something else". Even if that something else does work, it does not answer the original problem: Why __autoload does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `__autoload` function does a `require()`, which means it should die with a fatal error if the file is not found.  This means that there are two possibilities:

1. Your `__autoload` function is not being called
2. Your `__autoload` function is loading User.class.php, but that file does not define the class User_User

Add an `echo $path; die;` to your `__autoload` to see if it is actually being called and what it's trying to load.  Check that User.class.php does actually define the class User_User, and you don't have a typo in the class name.

Comment: It was the first one. Dont know why, seems like it should work, but it does not, not until using spl_autoload_register()